# How to prevent PHP's propagating session id from interfering ajax request

Tags: ajax, yii

I am experimenting with PHP's use_trans_sid.
I set use_trans_sid to 1.
With that, PHP will propagate session id to urls and forms.

In my case, I have ajax requests. Each request being sent to a controller (Yii controller). The controller will respond in json objects.

If the json object contain a form, PHP will insert a hidden variable (input type hidden). Somehow, this insertion interfering the ajax request, it causes the ajax request to fail.

Is there a way to make ajax request success with such insertion?

Comment: Maybe the Session_id is being send along with other URL parameters and therefore you'll need to adjust your routes to *tell* Yii that there'll be an extra parameter in each request?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida, no, that is not the case.